# ¿Cómo evitar múltiples sesiones de usuario en Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony4

¿Cómo puedo evitar que un usuario inicie sesión desde diferentes dispositivos o navegadores?

```
<?php


namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        //TODO validación para detectar si el usuario esta loggeado
    }


}
```

Hice este eventlistener pero no he encontrado como validar si el usuario ha iniciado sesión en otro dispositivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, para poder evitar el múltiple logueo de un mismo usuario puedes hacerlo simplemente con una **bandera**, esto requiere de un campo en la base de datos que cuando el usuario ingrese cambies el valor a 1 o algo con lo que tú identifiques que tiene una sesión activa, esto para que tu en el login si la bandera esta activada impides el acceso al usuario, pero tienes que tener mucho cuidado en como hacerlo ya que la forma lógica en la que esa bandera se desactivaría seria que el usuario presionara el botón de **cerrar sesión**, pero no puedes esperar que un usuario presione siempre dicho botón.

En muchas ocasiones el usuario nadamas va a cerrar el navegador y para esto tu debes de tener un tiempo determinado en el que se terminaría la sesión para que tú puedas desactivar la bandera, de lo contrario el usuario quedaría bloqueado y eso te ocasionaría problemas con los usuarios del sitio web.

Puedes simplemente crear un mecanismo con **AJAX** que cuando el usuario navegue entre pestañas este actualizando en la base de datos una hora, así puedes también determinar que cuando alguien trate de iniciar sesión de nuevo y si el último movimiento del usuario fue hace más de 20min entonces le permites el acceso de lo contrario puedes indicarle que le faltan tantos minutos para poder acceder o que simplemente ya hay una sesión activa. Aunque si son demasiados usuarios esto requeriría de más recursos para estar actualizando dicho campo cada que carguen una página del sitio.

No te adjunto nada de código debido a que a lo que yo veo es una cuestión de lógica independientemente de que framework estes utilizando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo había pensado hacer de esa manera, pero recuerdo que en Symfony al menos en la version 2.3 había ya una función para esa bandera de si un usuario estaba loggeado y en Symfony 4 no la he encontrado.